# LineChart Z-index in Lightningchart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am adding several rangeseries and linechart with below code

```
for(var i = 0;i<=8;i++)
{

   niftyseriesup[i] = chart[1].addAreaRangeSeries().setHighStrokeStyle(greenline).setLowStrokeStyle(greenline).setHighFillStyle(greencolors[i]);

 niftyseriesdown[i] = chart[1].addAreaRangeSeries().setHighStrokeStyle(redline).setHighFillStyle(redcolors[i]);

 if(i == 8)
 {


 setTimeout(function(){ 
   niftylineY = chart[1].addAxisY(true);
   niftylinechart = chart[1].addLineSeries({ dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive ,yAxis: niftylineY}).setMaxPointCount(8000);
  }, 200);

 }

}
```

I am adding the line chart at last , Still Its appear under the rangeseries chart sometimes.

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Can you add a minimal example that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: https://xtremealgo.com/test.php , I can replicate it only on multiple range series like this... also as time goes on .. it goes under other range series too.

Comment: This seems to be an issue inside the LightningChart JS library. I will continue to track it down but haven't had luck with it yet.

Comment: Ok thanks alot , please consider z-index parameter while adding series in next version.

Comment: hi @Snekw  : can you please check this question , thanks - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62560351/show-custom-tick-in-x-axis-on-hover

Comment: @Snekw : any update for this issue sir ?

Comment: We haven't been able to figure out the root cause for this yet.