# Toggle Series programatically in lighning chart

Tags: lightningchart

I have UI element and I am attaching series to it

```
box = legendBox.addElement(UIElementBuilders.CheckBox);
series.attach(box)
```

Now I click the series in legendbox it toggles my line series.Is there anyway we can click the checkbox programatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`UICheckBox`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.0.0/interfaces/uicheckbox.html) can be programmatically toggled on and off with the use of [`UICheckBox.setOn(isOn)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.0.0/interfaces/uicheckbox.html#seton) method.

The following code would toggle `lineSeries` on and off with 1 second interval.

```js
const ui = chart.addUIElement(UILayoutBuilders.Column)
const box = ui.addElement(UIElementBuilders.CheckBox)
lineSeries.attach(box)

setInterval(() => {
    box.setOn(!box.getOn())
}, 1000)
```

See below for full working example where the "Diesel" series is toggled on and off programmatically through the UICheckBox.

```js
// Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
const {
  lightningChart,
  SolidLine,
  SolidFill,
  ColorRGBA,
  AxisTickStrategies,
  UIOrigins,
  DataPatterns,
  Themes,
  UILayoutBuilders,
  UIElementBuilders,
} = lcjs

// Decide on an origin for DateTime axis.
const dateOrigin = new Date(2018, 8, 1)

// ----- Cache used styles -----
const customStrokeStyle = new SolidLine({
  fillStyle: new SolidFill({
    color: ColorRGBA(200, 50, 50)
  }),
  thickness: 2
})

// Create a XY Chart.
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
  // theme: Themes.dark
})
// Modify the default X Axis to use DateTime TickStrategy, and set the origin for the DateTime Axis.
chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime, (tickStrategy) => tickStrategy.setDateOrigin(dateOrigin))

chart.setPadding({
    right: 50
  })
  .setTitle('Diesel and Gasoline Price Comparison')

const diesel = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 1.52
  },
  {
    x: 1,
    y: 1.52
  },
  {
    x: 2,
    y: 1.52
  },
  {
    x: 3,
    y: 1.58
  },
  {
    x: 4,
    y: 2.00
  },
  {
    x: 5,
    y: 2.00
  },
  {
    x: 6,
    y: 2.00
  },
  {
    x: 7,
    y: 2.00
  },
  {
    x: 8,
    y: 2.26
  },
  {
    x: 9,
    y: 1.90
  },
  {
    x: 10,
    y: 1.90
  },
  {
    x: 11,
    y: 1.90
  },
  {
    x: 12,
    y: 1.90
  },
  {
    x: 13,
    y: 1.60
  },
  {
    x: 14,
    y: 1.60
  },
  {
    x: 15,
    y: 1.60
  },
  {
    x: 16,
    y: 1.00
  },
  {
    x: 17,
    y: 1.00
  },
  {
    x: 18,
    y: 1.00
  },
  {
    x: 19,
    y: 1.74
  },
  {
    x: 20,
    y: 1.47
  },
  {
    x: 21,
    y: 1.47
  },
  {
    x: 22,
    y: 1.47
  },
  {
    x: 23,
    y: 1.74
  },
  {
    x: 24,
    y: 1.74
  },
  {
    x: 25,
    y: 1.74
  },
  {
    x: 27,
    y: 1.5
  },
  {
    x: 28,
    y: 1.5
  },
  {
    x: 29,
    y: 1.5
  }
]

const gasoline = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 1.35
  },
  {
    x: 1,
    y: 1.35
  },
  {
    x: 2,
    y: 1.35
  },
  {
    x: 3,
    y: 1.35
  },
  {
    x: 4,
    y: 1.90
  },
  {
    x: 5,
    y: 1.90
  },
  {
    x: 6,
    y: 1.90
  },
  {
    x: 7,
    y: 1.92
  },
  {
    x: 8,
    y: 1.50
  },
  {
    x: 9,
    y: 1.50
  },
  {
    x: 10,
    y: 1.3
  },
  {
    x: 11,
    y: 1.3
  },
  {
    x: 12,
    y: 1.3
  },
  {
    x: 13,
    y: 1.3
  },
  {
    x: 14,
    y: 1.3
  },
  {
    x: 15,
    y: 1.32
  },
  {
    x: 16,
    y: 1.40
  },
  {
    x: 17,
    y: 1.44
  },
  {
    x: 18,
    y: 1.02
  },
  {
    x: 19,
    y: 1.02
  },
  {
    x: 20,
    y: 1.02
  },
  {
    x: 21,
    y: 1.02
  },
  {
    x: 22,
    y: 1.02
  },
  {
    x: 23,
    y: 1.02
  },
  {
    x: 24,
    y: 1.02
  },
  {
    x: 25,
    y: 1.02
  },
  {
    x: 27,
    y: 1.30
  },
  {
    x: 28,
    y: 1.30
  },
  {
    x: 29,
    y: 1.30
  }
]

// Add two line series.
const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries()
  .setName('Diesel')

const lineSeries2 = chart.addLineSeries()
  .setName('Gasoline')
  .setStrokeStyle(customStrokeStyle)

// Set the correct value to use for the data frequency.
// 1000ms * 60s * 60min * 24h
const dataFrequency = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

// Add the points to each Series - the X values are multiplied by dataFrequency to set the values properly on the X Axis.
lineSeries2.add(diesel.map((point) => ({
  x: point.x * dataFrequency,
  y: point.y
})))
lineSeries.add(gasoline.map((point) => ({
  x: point.x * dataFrequency,
  y: point.y
})))

// Setup view nicely.
chart.getDefaultAxisY()
  .setTitle('$/litre')
  .setInterval(0, 3, false, true)

// Enable AutoCursor auto-fill.
chart.setAutoCursor(cursor => cursor
  .setResultTableAutoTextStyle(true)
  .disposeTickMarkerX()
  .setTickMarkerYAutoTextStyle(true)
)
const legend = chart.addLegendBox()

// Add Chart to LegendBox.
legend.add(chart)

const ui = chart.addUIElement(UILayoutBuilders.Column)
const box = ui.addElement(UIElementBuilders.CheckBox)
lineSeries.attach(box)

setInterval(() => {
  box.setOn(!box.getOn())
}, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.0.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you , you are back -- can you please check if this is possible ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482988/draw-lines-from-one-x-axis-to-another-x-axis/67499518